# Ajax html table append does not recognize jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax, model-view-controller

I'm trying to output a message when a table row is selected, the HTML table body is being constructed in my controller, then appending this to my table in the view, via Ajax. The data is being constructed as expected, but when I click on a table row, nothing happens.

Even though I'm setting the `clickable` class in the `<tr>`, something seems to get lost in translation when it gets appended to the view. In chrome, I can do an inspect element and can see the table has the `clickable` class. As a sanity test, I hardcoded a dummy table in the view that calls that same jQuery function. Works like a charm.

Why does the message does not get executed when I construct the table body in my Controller?

Controller

```
var t = "";  

foreach (var item in associateResults.monthly_hierarchy)
{
    t += @"<tr class=""clickable"">";
    t += "<td>" + item.AgentName + "</td>";
    t += "<td>" + item.AgentSSOn + "</td>";
    t += "<td>" + item.Site + "</td>";
    t += "<td>" + item.BusGroup + "</td>";
    t += "<td>" + item.MgrName + "</td>";
    t += "</tr>";
}

return Content(t);
```

jQuery

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $(".clickable").click(function() {
     alert("hello")
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question states that the table is loaded with ajax.  What this means is the elements will not exist on page load.  So your bind in the document ready will not find any elements to bind on.  You either need to perform your binding after the fields are created, OR more preferably, create a delegate binding that doesn't care when the fields are created.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $(selectorForTable).on("click", ".clickable", function() {
        alert("hello")
    });
});
```

What this does is puts a click event handler on the table, which does exist on page load.  It listens for click events from any child element that it has, or will have, and if they match the childSelector (".clickable" in this case) it will perform the logic.

Comment: Thanks Taplar. I tried you example, but still no luck. I updated my jQuery to exactly what you had. Thoughts?

Comment: "exactly" what I have?  `$(selectorForTable)` is a place holder, you got that right? @GRU119